# How are colors for facets in persp() selected?

Tags: r, graphics

This question is about `graphics::persp` .  I'm trying to figure out what order the values in the `colors` argument are applied to the facets.  For example, I wanted to do something similar to the `drape` argument in `lattice::wireframe` , where the color is a function of the z-values.  I tried a simple example:

```
gairy<- matrix(rep(1,61^2),nr=61)
gairy[20:40,20:40]<-10
fairy<- matrix(nc=61,nr=61)
fairy[,]<-rainbow(20)[gairy]
persp(gairy,col=fairy)
```

(hope this works -- limited choice of posting from work)
https://plus.google.com/photos/102564725150183579541/albums/5779881398012083153

But the color assignments show up in rather strange places.  I'm pretty sure from this and other experiments that the colors are not applied in any row or column-ordered sequence. Can anyone shed some light on this, i.e. how to order my "colors" array to match the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is that the primary matrix passed to `persp` denotes the height of the nodes, while the colors refer to **facets** -- i.e. the dimensions of the color matrix should be one smaller than the dimensions of the node-height matrix. Recycling could give you weird-looking results.

For example, this looks reasonable:

```
persp(matrix(1:16,nrow=4),col=rainbow(9))
```

Comment: Looks like you're correct -- first because it's consistent with that diagonal offset in my image, and second because changing to  `persp(gairy,col=fairy[1:60,1:60])`  mapped the colors exactly right.  Thanks!

Comment: I should also smack myself for reading the documentation to `persp` and ignoring the statement "This is recycled to the (nx-1)(ny-1) facets."